# Why use buffered input in C?

Tags: c

I read below line in one book about "buffered input"

> Why have buffers? First, it is less time-consuming to transmit several
>   characters as a block than to send them one by one

Please explain what is meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why have buffers? First, it is less time-consuming to transmit several
>   characters as a block than to send them one by one

Let's say I'm your boss. I really like waffles but the store is 20 minutes away, and you have to run through zombie-infested badlands. So from time to time I send you to buy ONE. Wouldn't it be better if you could just buy ten at a time ?

Comment: Couldn't you have used a car analogy instead?

Comment: @BrianRoach Maybe, it was just the first thing that came to my mind :-)

Comment: The fact that zombie-infested badlands is the first thing that comes to your mind makes me think you need to lay off the LFD2 :-D

Comment: +1 But ... but ... do zombies like waffles as much as the boss? By  buying ten at a time your risk of losing waffles is that much greater :)

Comment: @cnicutar: thank you for answer but i know!!i mean is there another reason???I am looking for another reason!

Comment: @AS You simply need to be aware that fetching a character from the kernel involves a system call (in the simplest case, a `read`). For various reasons making a system call and switching the context is hard and takes a lot of time. That's all there is to it.